# Jenkins STAGE_NAME enviroment variable is null

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline I'm sending a message to Slack via slackSend. However, when I add the enviroment variable `env.STAGE_NAME` it returns null. I've also tried: `${STAGE_NAME}` and`${env.STAGE_NAME}`, but these throw an error

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Update: added code

```
node{
    try {
    // send build started notification
        stage("Build start notification"){
            slackSend (color: '#FFFF00', message: "STARTED: Job '${env.STAGE_NAME} ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
        }
    //reference the sonar tool and start the analysis of the proxy
        stage("SonarQube analysis") {
        withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube'){
                def sonarScanner = tool name: 'scanner', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation'
                bat "${sonarScanner}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=test -Dsonar.sources=apiproxy"
          }
        }
    //wait for webhook from sonarqube. Break build if qyalitygate not ok.
        stage("Quality Gate"){
            timeout(time: 10, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                def qg = waitForQualityGate()
                if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                    error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
                    slackSend (color: '#FF0000', message: "QualityGate error '${qg.status}")
                }
            }
        }
    //Deploy the apiproxy
        stage ('Build & deploy') {
            withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_5_4'){
                def maven = tool name: 'maven_3_5_4', type: 'maven'
                bat 'mvn clean install -Ptest'
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e){
            slackSend (color: '#FF0000', message: "Failure '${env.STAGE_NAME} ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' (${env.BUILD_URL})")
    }
    finally {
    // send build finished notification 
        slackSend (color: '#00FF00', message: """FINISHED: Job "${env.STAGE_NAME} ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]" (${env.BUILD_URL})""")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @oblio added code

Comment: You're using the scripted pipelines, no? Based on your syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
finally {
// send build finished notification 
  slackSend (color: '#00FF00', message: """FINISHED: Job "${env.STAGE_NAME} ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]" (${env.BUILD_URL})""")
}
```

You had a quoting problem and a variable interpolation problem, from what I see.

Comment: I tried it. It worked. However, when the pipeline throws an error in the try block it goes to the catch and finally. These don't have stage names, which is why it's set as null. Any tips as how to rewrite this (not have the try catch in some way, but do have error message)?

Comment: You could try to have a Groovy variable defined at the top of the script and then set the variable in one of the stages to the name of the stage. This variable and its value should still be visible in the finally block.